# How to localize activerecord model value with Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, localization, internationalization

I want to localize model values within form helpers.

For example I have 2 models, Role and User, defined by the relation : role has_many users.

To create a new user I have in my controller something like this :

```
@user = User.new
@roles = Role.all # role title return values "admin" or "customer" only
```

And in my form I have something like this :

```
f.collection_select :role_id, @roles, :id, :title, {:selected => (@user.role)}
```

How can I localize role title values?

I used to set my localization in config/locales files. Can I set activerecord model values in this way?

Thank you for your help!

Jeremy.

Answer (score 0):

[Globalize2](https://github.com/joshmh/globalize2) is one solution for data i18n. I've not used it though, so don't ask me if it eats your wife.